# What does מחיה מתים אתה mean?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk

In the Amidah, does מחיה מתים אתה mean "You revive the dead" or "You are a reviver of the dead"?

If it means the former, how does God presently revive the dead?

Please provide evidence (textual, reason or other) for your answer.

Comment: I've always understood the phrase in the latter sense. My understanding of the blessing as a whole is that it is listing God's qualities (i.e. the ways in which he is גיבור/mighty), not the actions he is [presently/now] taking.

Answer (score 2):

See the commentary of the [Abudarham](https://www.sefaria.org/Abudarham%2C_Weekday_Prayers%2C_Amidah.14?vhe=Abudarham._Lisbon,_1489.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) on the weekday prayers:

> אתה גבור לעולם ה' על שם ה' כגבור יצא. ואמ' בתחלת ברכה זו לשון גבורה שכל אלה שמזכיר בברכה זו הם בגבורה כמו שנפרש. ומזכיר בברכה זו שלשה פעמים תחיית המתים הראשונה מחיה מתים אתה והשנית מחיה מתים ברחמים רבים והשלישית בא"י מחיה המתים. והטעם כי בשלשה עניינים הב"ה מחיה המתים, הראשונה כשאדם ישן על מטתו והרי הוא חשוב כמת ואומר בידך אפקיד רוחי והב"ה מעלה עננים ומוריד טללים וגשמים כדי לפרנסו ומחזיר לו נשמתו לכך נסמך זה לזה מחיה מתים אתה [...]

The Abudarham explains that "reviver of the dead" also implies that G-d restores our soul, and we can wake up. That's why, says the Abudarham, we say during Krias Shema al HaMitah, "in your hand I entrust my spirit". This is what the [Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.57b.13?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) means: sleep is one-sixtieth of death; and a dream is one-sixtieth of prophecy.

However, it might also mean that G-d will revive us, Techiyas HaMeisim, as it [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.85.7?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Surely You will revive us again,

Answer (score 2):

In Rav Schwab on prayer page 424 he says, "The gevurah of HaKadosh Brauch Hu in negating the Malach Hamaves is in preparation for the creation of a new, higher form of life, that of techiyas hameisim. Thus, אתה גבור לעולם means, Your Gevurah does not stop at extinguishing the existence of the Malach hamaves, but rather, it lasts forever as manifested by techiyas hameisim."

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeyaShetig101  and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 0):

The Gemara in Bava Metzia 85b cites a story:

> Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said to Elijah: And is there anyone alive in this
> world who is comparable to them and can produce such efficacious
> prayers? Elijah said to him: There are Rabbi Ḥiyya and his sons. Rabbi
> Yehuda HaNasi decreed a fast, and the Sages brought Rabbi Ḥiyya and
> his sons down to the pulpit to pray on behalf of the congregation.
> Rabbi Ḥiyya recited the phrase in the Amida prayer: Who makes the wind
> blow, and the wind blew. Rabbi Ḥiyya recited the next phrase: Who
> makes the rain fall, and rain fell. When he was about to say the
> phrase: Who revives the dead (מחיה **ה**מתים), the world trembled.

(Sefaria/Steinsaltz translation and commentary)

Ritva (Mosad Harav Kook ed. pg. תשכ) there appears to be wondering why the world only began to shake when they reached the end of the bracha since תחית המתים was already mentioned earlier. He thus clarifies:

> כי מטא לתחיית המתים רגש עלמא: ואע"ג דמקמי הכי אדכר תחיית המתים בראש
> הברכה אתה גבור וכו' מחיה מתים **ההיא אינה אלא להחיות חיים שהגיעו לשערי
> מות** אבל תחיית המתים העתידה היא של סוף הברכה

Accordingly, מחיה מתים אתה can mean "You revive the dead" and yet it refers to the times when God "revives" someone who is about to die.

Comment: Another explanation of the Gemara is that Rabbi Hiyya had a text that didn't include the words מחיה מתים אתה. Such a text is attested in the Cairo geniza.

Comment: @magicker72 great point, but it seems that will only work for the second mention of תחיית המתים in the bracha, whereas according to Ritva's answer, the two subsequent times it is mentioned can also be referring to near-death salvation. (I understand that I'm extending his answer but it seems he would have to say that.) Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. Ritva can easily be understood to say that in both place God is _reviver_ (and not that He _revives_). The distinction Ritva makes is that in the first mention (מחיה מתים) God is "reviver of dead" (i.e. that can, and does, bring individuals back to life, from death), and that in the second mention (מחיה **ה**מתים) He is "reviver of **the** dead" (i.e. that can, and will, revive the dead, in the Resurrection/תחית המתים).

Comment: @TamirEvan I wasn't entirely clear. You are correct; it answers the second question, not the first. My point was that Ritva allows for both readings (reviver and revive), whereas a typical interpretation of מחיה מתים would not. My motivation in asking the question was because I prefer the "You revive" translation but I could not see how this would make sense before I saw the Ritva.

Comment: To clarify: I always personally translated מחיה מתים אתה as "You revive the dead" but I never understood how God revives the dead in present times. I've never seen or heard of someone rising from the dead nowadays. Now, with this Ritva, I can understand the bracha and maintain my translation.

Comment: I still don't see how this Ritva answers the question. If the first instance ("מחיה מתים אתה") means "You revive (the) dead", in present times, then the last instance ("מחיה המתים") should also mean "[who] revives _the_ dead", in present times. If the last is referring to the Resurrection (תחית המתים), as this Ritva suggests, how does _that_ happen in present times? All your answer seems to do is shift the problem from  "מחיה מתים אתה" to "מחיה המתים", and make the problem stronger for the latter.

Comment: @TamirEvan that is a strong objection. I was assuming מחיה המתים is more readily translated as "reviver of the dead", but I don't know why I thought that. Is there any basis for that? Can anyone knowledgeable in hebrew grammar weigh in on the dikduk here?

Comment: @Yehuda In the opening of the question, you acknowledged 2 ways of reading "מחיה מתים אתה", and chose one of them (that led to the question itself). Considering the problem your choice presented when applied to this answer, doesn't that mean you should now choose the other way of reading "מחיה מתים אתה"?

Comment: @TamirEvan Ah. I guess you're noting that it seems I'm not being so intellectually honest here. Perhaps you're right. I don't know if a problem with my way if reading it necessarily disproves it though; it just makes it a less likely alternative. I happen to still connect with my way of reading more but you're right that my answer is problematic. What's the protocol in this case- do we delete it?